# How to support modified data interpretations in NumPy ndarrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to write a Python 3 class that stores some data in a NumPy `np.ndarray`. However, I want my class to also contain a piece of information about how to interpret the data values.

For example, let's assume the `dtype` of the `ndarray` is `np.float32`, but there is also a "**color**" that modifies the meaning of those floating-point values. So, if I want to add a **red** number and a **blue** number, I must first convert both numbers to **magenta** in order to legally add their underlying `_data` arrays. The result of the addition will then have `_color = "magenta"`.

This is just a toy example. In reality, the "color" is not a string (it's better to think of it as an integer), the "color" of the result is mathematically determined from the "color" of the two inputs, and the conversion between any two "colors" is mathematically defined.

```py
class MyClass:
    
    def __init__(self, data : np.ndarray, color : str):
        self._data = data
        self._color = color
    
    
    # Example: Adding red numbers and blue numbers produces magenta numbers
    def convert(self, other_color):
        if self._color == "red" and other_color == "blue":
            return MyClass(10*self._data, "magenta")
        elif self._color == "blue" and other_color == "red":
            return MyClass(self._data/10, "magenta")
    
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        if other._color == self._color:
            # If the colors match, then just add the data values
            return MyClass(self._data + other._data, self._color)
        else:
            # If the colors don't match, then convert to the output color before adding
            new_self = self.convert(other._color)
            new_other = other.convert(self._color)
            return new_self + new_other
```

My problem is that the `_color` information lives **alongside** the `_data`. So, I can't seem to define sensible indexing behavior for my class:

- If I define `__getitem__` to return `self._data[i]`, then the `_color` information is lost.
- If I define `__getitem__` to return `MyClass(self._data[i], self._color)` then I'm creating a new object that contains a scalar number. This will cause plenty of problems (for example, I can legally index `that_object[i]`, leading to certain error.
- If I define `__getitem__` to return `MyClass(self._data[i:i+1], self._color)` then I'm indexing an array to get an array, which leads to plenty of other problems. For example, `my_object[i] = my_object[i]` looks sensible, but would throw an error.

I then started thinking that what I really want is a different `dtype` for each different "color". That way, the indexed value would have the "color" information encoded for free in the `dtype`... but I don't know how to implement that.

The theoretical total number of "colors" is likely to be roughly 100,000. However, fewer than 100 would be used in any single script execution. So, I guess it may be possible to maintain a list/dictionary/? of the used "colors" and how they map to dynamically generated classes ... but Python tends to quietly convert types in ways I don't expect, so that is probably not the right path to go down.

All I know is that I don't want to store the "color" alongside every data value. The data arrays can be ~billions of entries, with one "color" for all entries.

How can I keep track of this "color" information, while also having a usable class?

Comment: To do something like `my_object[i] = ...` you'll have to define a `__setitem__` method.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Your class reminds me of the `np.ma` masked array class.  Except that has a `mask` that's normally the same size as the data.  `recarray` is just a regular structured array with a modified `getitem`, which gives access to fields as attributes.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for the tips - I will look into them. I have been struggling with this problem for about 2 years, so all ideas are welcome.

Comment: @hpaulj I initially thought anything akin to a "mask" would waste too much memory (because the mask needs the same dimensions as the data). However, I think a custom container class could eliminate this problem. The NumPy [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.dispatch.html) shows how an arbitrarily large diagonal matrix can be implemented by storing just one number. My arbitrarily large "color mask" would also only store one number. Interesting food for thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not tenable to define every dunder (`__add__`, etc.) It's also probably not tenable to inherit from `np.ndarray`, which is what it would take for a compatible derived class.

You can get away with a thin wrapper:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple, Sequence, Any, Callable

import numpy as np

Colour = int
RED: Colour = 0x0000FF
MAGENTA: Colour = 0xFF00FF
BLUE: Colour = 0xFF0000


def common_colour(colours: Sequence[Colour]) -> Colour:
    # magic happens here
    return sum(colours)


class ColouredArray(NamedTuple):
    colour: Colour
    data: np.ndarray

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'({self.colour}) {self.data}'

    def convert(self, new_colour: Colour) -> 'ColouredArray':
        return ColouredArray(
            # magic happens here
            data=self.data * new_colour/self.colour,
            colour=new_colour,
        )


def all_common(arrays: Sequence['ColouredArray']) -> tuple['ColouredArray']:
    new_colour = common_colour([a.colour for a in arrays])
    return tuple(
        array.convert(new_colour) for array in arrays
    )


def call_common(method: Callable, *args, **kwargs) -> tuple[Colour, Any]:
    new_colour = common_colour([
        arg.colour
        for arg in (*args, *kwargs.values())
        if isinstance(arg, ColouredArray)
    ])
    return new_colour, method(
        *(
            arg.convert(new_colour).data if isinstance(arg, ColouredArray) else arg
            for arg in args
        ),
        **{
            k: arg.convert(new_colour).data if isinstance(arg, ColouredArray) else arg
            for k, arg in kwargs.items()
        },
    )


y = ColouredArray(*call_common(
    np.interp,
    x=ColouredArray(RED, np.arange(5)),
    xp=ColouredArray(RED, np.arange(1, 30, 2)),
    fp=ColouredArray(BLUE, np.arange(11, 40, 2)),
    left=-1,
))
print(y)
```

In this example, the tuple from `call_common` is unpacked directly into the `ColouredArray` constructor because `interp` returns a single `np.ndarray`. In other situations such as the 4-tuple returned from `numpy.linalg.lstsq` it would be up to the caller to unpack and reconstruct a coloured array as needed.

Comment: I had to do some googling to learn some new Python syntax, but this seems quite ingenious. As far as I understand, `call_common` strips off the colour information, calls the `method` on the internal data and then re-attaches the colour info. I will work through this today.